# TFS: Stop Team Build process has updated the Fixed In field messages

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-workitem

We have an interesting situation.  Our build server seems to want to go back to previously closed work items and update the Integration Build field.

I understand the build server setting it the first time.  I could even understand it updating that field in the event that the first build didn't complete successfully.

However, I can't understand why it continues to update all of the previously closed work items with a new integration build number.

Note that none of the relevant work item doesn't show up in the associated work items list for the defined build.

Thanks,

Comment: This is probably a server fault question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that not all of the solutions that referenced the apps were building.

We had CI turned on for all of the different solutions (10 or so) which referenced a number of common projects.  When one of those solutions failed to build, it would update all of the related work items in the TFS project... even if they didn't apply to the particular solution.

Once we resolved the build failures, this stopped happening.